# Why is my splitting being over ambitious?

Tags: java, split

In this class I'm splitting variables on different delimiters(namely || and &&)

Here is my class:

```
public class Test {


    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String orStatement = "here||there";
        String andStatement = "here&&there";
        splitOr(orStatement);
        splitAnd(andStatement);
    }
    public static String[] splitOr(String stringvar){

        if(!stringvar.contains("||")){
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("Must contain a double pipe || to split into or statements");
        }
        String[] orArray = stringvar.split("||");
        for(int i=0;i<orArray.length;i++){
            System.out.println(orArray[i]);
        }
        return orArray;
    }

    public static String[] splitAnd(String stringvar){

        if(!stringvar.contains("&&")){
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("Must contain a double ampersand && to split into and statements");
        }
        String[] andArray = stringvar.split("&&");
        for(int i=0;i<andArray.length;i++){
            System.out.println(andArray[i]);
        }
        return andArray;
    }
}
```

And here is the result:

```
h
e
r
e
|
|
t
h
e
r
e
here
there
```

Why am I getting this weird ambitious splitting?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's because [`split` expects a regular expression](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#split%28java.lang.String%29), and `|` has a special meaning when used inside a regex. You need to escape the pipes with a slash (which itself needs to be escaped in a Java String):

```
String[] orArray = stringvar.split("\\|\\|");
```

Comment: This makes sense, I guess `"|"` is matching the 'character' between letters?